# PouchDB allDocs range with semver

Tags: pouchdb

Is there any way to have an `allDocs` query respect semantic versions for order and range (semver, eg `1.0.2`):

For example:

```
    const res = await db.allDocs({
      startkey: `/myThing/1.0.0`,
      endkey: `/myThing/1.5.2`,
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Comparison of strings is done using ICU which implements the Unicode Collation Algorithm, giving a `dictionary sorting` of keys. This can give surprising results if you were expecting ASCII ordering. Quoted from: [Collation Specification](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/ddocs/views/collation.html#collation-specification)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a word: No.

Longer answer: If you have the freedom to be creative with your version strings, you can approximate something similar.  Indexes do string-based comparison for sorting, so you need to convert your values into something that sorts alpha-numerically the same as semver.  This is relatively easy for semver (given certain range limitations), by using a fixed size for each version component. That is to say, if you always use two or three digits for each version component, the sorting will work.

i.e.:

- 1.0.0 becomes `001.000.000`
- 1.5.2 becomes `001.005.002`
- 10.9.100 becomes `010.009.100`

This, of course, only works for values that range from 0 to 999. If you have version components of 1000 or higher, you'll need to move to a 4-digit solution, etc. This also doesn't handle the optional parts used in some semver scheme, such as the `-rc1` in `1.0.0-rc1`.  But typically, these parts sort alphanumerically anyway, so in most cases, this won't need any extra consideration.